# How to compare dates using javascript and print a higher date in textbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a task manager application. For that i want to create a task. The tasks may depend on other tasks(multiple). So i made the dropdown to list all the previous tasks. The problem is i want to compare the ending dates of the multiple selected task and the higher date should be the start date of the new task. I have done something to get the value and print it in the text box. I don't know how to compare the date values and print it to the textbox. I am beginner of javascript. Can anyone help me? I posted the code below.

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<select multiple name="pre_task" id="pre_task" onChange="change()">
<?php

while($t_res=mysql_fetch_array($t_que))
{
   echo "<option value='$t_res[t_id]'>$t_res[t_name]</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<?php
$t_que1=mysql_query("select * from task where p_id=$_SESSION[p_id]");
while($t_res1=mysql_fetch_array($t_que1))
{
  echo "<input type='hidden' value='$t_res1[t_to]' id='$t_res1[t_id]'> ";
}
?>
<label>Start Date</label>
<input type="text" id="from" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function getselected(selectobject) 
{
  var results = {};
  for (var i=0; i<selectobject.options.length; i++) 
  {
    var option = selectobject.options[i];
    var value = option.value;
    results[value] = option.selected;
  }
  return results;
}
var currentselect = {};
function change () 
{
   var selectobject = document.getElementById("pre_task");
   var newselect = getselected(selectobject);
   for (var k in newselect) 
   {
      if (currentselect[k] != newselect[k]) 
      {
        if (newselect[k]) 
        {
          var TextBox = document.getElementById("from");
          TextBox.value = document.getElementById(k).value;
        }
      }
    } 
 currentselect = newselect;
 }
```

Now i made this to get the last selected date and print it to textbox

Thank you in advance

Comment: i m not sure but you can use "select MAX(end_date) from task where p_id=$_SESSION[p_id]"

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 1):

Convert your both date values into [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) and then perform comparison using usual comparison operators.

Answer (score 0):

getTime() method of javascript Date returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970, so we can use

> dateObj1.getTime()-dateObj2.getTime()

to find the difference. From this we can find the largest end date

Comment: @sohel khalifa If you see there i just get the value selected in the dropdown and then while displaying i just displayed the value of the textbox hidden using the id. I want to know how to get the dates in textbox hidden and and pass it to getselected function